# Autocomplete input suggestions

Tags: html, input, autocomplete, xmlhttprequest, here-api

I'm trying to set up an input with autocomplete places list. I want to use Here autosuggest tool.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-autosuggest-brief.html

For this I did this code :

```
<div class="autocomplete input-group has-warning">
        <input id="search-where" name="w" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="A quel endroit?" required="required" value="" autocomplete="on" onkeyup="mySearch(this.value)" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"></span></button>
        </span>
    </div>

    {literal}
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function mySearch(e){
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/suggest",
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    at: '44.771079,5.742806',
                    q: 'savoie',
                    app_id: '2FXOZOY',
                    app_code: 'b_9sMKgQmSjWUj1rlyY0wI'
                  },
                headers : { "Authorization": "Bearer" + $('b_9sMKgQ5qzJF0SusExJJx9irrHHimSjWUj1rlyY0wI').val()},
                  beforeSend: function(xhr){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
                  },
                  success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                  }
            });
            $( "#search-where" ).autocomplete({
                source: mySearch 
            });
        }               
        </script>
    {/literal}
```

But I get this error when I try to write in the input : 
[image]

I'm clearly completely lost ... If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated.
Thanks for reading me anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing an XMLHttpRequest to a different URL than the page you are on. In such scenarios, browser blocks it completely giving CORS error due to security reasons. There are a lot of ways to set this. A [tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) is available here.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer me I'm going to try this